# Points on circle according to mouse position

Tags: javascript, math, processing

What I need to do is to create a function that will take the lines you are drawing with your mouse on HTML5 canvas and sort of mirror them X times around the circle. What I have come up with is the function bellow. It works almost fine. It does everything I need. Except it rotates in the opposite direction than the mouse.

```
void mirroring(x1,y1,x2,y2){

  var mirrorNumber = 6;

  for(var i = 1; i < mirrorNumber;i++){
    var distance1 = dist(x1,y1,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
    var distance2 = dist(x2,y2,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);

    var deltaY1 = y1-window.innerHeight/2;
    var deltaX1 = x1-window.innerWidth/2;

    var deltaY2 = y2-window.innerHeight/2;
    var deltaX2 = x2-window.innerWidth/2;

    var angle1 = atan2(deltaY1, deltaX1);
    var angle2 = atan2(deltaY2, deltaX2);

    var newX1 = window.innerWidth/2 + distance1 * sin(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
    var newY1 = window.innerHeight/2 + distance1 * cos(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);

    var newX2 = window.innerWidth/2 + distance2 * sin(angle2-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
    var newY2 = window.innerHeight/2 + distance2 * cos(angle2-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);

    line(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2);

  }

};
```

this is what it produces:

[image]

I guess that it needs just a slight change but I can't figure it out. If something isn't clear, just ask me any question.

Thanks.

EDIT:

the final code that works how it is supposed to.

void mirroring(x1,y1,x2,y2){

```
var mirrorNumber = 6;
var deltaAngle = TWO_PI / mirrorNumber;

var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

var distance1 = dist(x1,y1,centerX, centerY);
var distance2 = dist(x2,y2,centerX, centerY);

var deltaY1 = y1-centerY;
var deltaX1 = x1-centerX;

var deltaY2 = y2-centerY;
var deltaX2 = x2-centerX;

var angle1 = atan2(deltaY1, deltaX1);
var angle2 = atan2(deltaY2, deltaX2);

for(var i = 1; i < mirrorNumber;i++){
    // note use of '+' instead of '-' in calls to sin() and cos()
    var newX1 = window.innerWidth /2 - distance1 * sin(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
    var newY1 = window.innerHeight/2 + distance1 * cos(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);

    var newX2 = window.innerWidth /2 - distance2 * sin(angle2-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
    var newY2 = window.innerHeight/2 + distance2 * cos(angle2-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);

    line(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2);
}
```

};

Comment: What is `void mirroring(x1,y1,x2,y2)`? That doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I'm using processingjs which is a port of processing a library for java. So it is kinda mixed. But it has nothing to do with the funcionality.

Comment: An image with the actual and the expected result would be helpful.

Comment: I have added a picture of what it produces...you can see the top arrow pointing other way than the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer might already be posted.  But, in my experience in using this trig formula, I had to subtract the from the x-coordinate and add to the y-coordinate.  Since the y axis goes down instead of up.  Without looking into your code too much I would suggest:

```
var newX1 = window.innerWidth /2 - distance1 * sin(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
var newY1 = window.innerHeight/2 + distance1 * cos(angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i);
```

and the same for newX2.  I did not look into the `angle1-(TWO_PI/mirrorNumber)*i` part of your code.  But changing the direction of one of the coordinates for your circle drawing (x) would keep it

> from going in the opposite direction than the mouse

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should simply be adding `i*TWO_PI/mirrorNumber` instead of subtracting it. Also, you have a lot of calculations that can be moved out of the loop.

```
void mirroring(x1,y1,x2,y2){

    var mirrorNumber = 6;
    var deltaAngle = TWO_PI / mirrorNumber;

    var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var distance1 = dist(x1,y1,centerX, centerY);
    var distance2 = dist(x2,y2,centerX, centerY);

    var deltaY1 = y1-centerY;
    var deltaX1 = x1-centerX;

    var deltaY2 = y2-centerY;
    var deltaX2 = x2-centerX;

    var angle1 = atan2(deltaY1, deltaX1);
    var angle2 = atan2(deltaY2, deltaX2);

    for(var i = 1; i < mirrorNumber;i++){
        // note use of '+' instead of '-' in calls to sin() and cos()
        var newX1 = centerX + distance1 * sin(angle1 + i * deltaAngle);
        var newY1 = centerY + distance1 * cos(angle1 + i * deltaAngle);

        var newX2 = centerX + distance2 * sin(angle2 + i * deltaAngle);
        var newY2 = centerY + distance2 * cos(angle2 + i * deltaAngle);

        line(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you definitely made my code more efficient. However it produced exactly the same result. I have tried to switch the + and - before and it has no effect.